# How to send the data to view which is included as header?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have one file `header.php`, which is included as header in other views file. so I need to send some data to the `header.php`.

here is my `home_view`:

```
<?php include("include/header.php"); ?>

<div class="container">
<?php include("include/sidebar.php"); ?>

 <-- here content of current view -->
</div>
<?php include("include/footer.php"); ?>
```

Here is controller home:

```
class Admin_home extends CI_Controller {
  function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('admin/home_model');
}       
public function index() {        
if($this->session->userdata('admin_in')) {
$result = $this->admin_home_model->get_user_count();
if($result) {
$data['user_counts'] = $result; 

$this->load->view('admin/home_view', $data);  
}
```

I have user that data in `header.php`, It work properly in `home_view` but when I tried to load any another view in which the file `header.php` is also included, so it gaves the undefined index  error.
I expecting a way in which I can pass the data from controller to header that is included recursively 
in all other views.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following instead.

**View:**

```
    div class="container">
<?php $this->load->view('sidebar'); ?>

 <-- here content of current view -->
</div>
```

**Controller**

```
     class Admin_home extends CI_Controller {
      function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('admin/home_model');
    }       
    public function index() {        
    if($this->session->userdata('admin_in')) {
       $result = $this->admin_home_model->get_user_count();
    if($result) {
       $data['user_counts'] = $result; 
       $this->load->view('header');  
       $this->load->view('admin/home_view', $data);  
       $this->load->view('footer');  
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `<?php include("include/header.php"); ?>` use `<?php $this->load->view('header'); ?>`

Comment: I need to add the notification information in header, so which view should load no matter each time any view is loaded at the same time I want to put the notification information in header portion.

Comment: I know, if you use `$this->load->view('header')` inside your view, the variables you pass to the view from the controller will be available in the views loaded by the view.